Computing $\pi_1$ of $S^1\times [0,1]$ using Van-Kampen theorem
Let $X$ be a cylinder, realized as the quotient of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ by the relation $(0,x)\sim (1,x)$. Write $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for the top and bottom edges of $X$, respectively, and $\gamma$ for the identified side edge.
To practice using the SvK theorem, I want to compute $\pi_1(X)$ using SvK. In particular, I want to practice determining the maps induced on $\pi_1$ by subspace inclusions, since I am often confused by this. I am aware that there are easier ways to compute $\pi_1(S^1\times [0,1])$.
Here is my attempt:
Write $X=U\cup V$, where $U$ is $X\setminus \{(1/2,1/2)\}$ , and $V$ is an open disc around $(1/2,1/2)$. Then $U$ deformation retracts onto $S^1 \vee S^1$, $V$ is contractible, and $U\cap V$ deformation retracts onto $S^1$.
Passing to $\pi_1$, we have that $\pi_1(U)=\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle$, $\pi_1(V)=1$, and $\pi_1(U\cap V)=\langle \alpha \gamma \beta \gamma^{-1} \rangle$. Clearly the induced map $\pi_1(U\cap V)\to \pi_1(V)$ is trivial. On the other hand, the induced map $\pi_1(U\cap V)\to \pi_1(U)$ is given by $\alpha \gamma \beta \gamma^{-1} \mapsto \alpha \beta$. Thus, by SvK theorem, $\pi_1(X)=\langle \alpha, \beta \mid \alpha \beta =1\rangle = \langle \alpha, \beta \mid \beta = \alpha^{-1} \rangle = \langle \alpha \rangle \cong \mathbb Z$.
Question: This gives the right answer, but is my induced map $\pi_1(U\cap V)\to \pi_1(U)$ and reasoning thereafter correct? Is there anything imprecise or unclear about what I've written?

Can you compute $\pi_1(S^1)$ using SVK? Somehow, I do not think so. Are you taking $\pi_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb Z$ for granted?

@MoisheKohan At least not by just looking at $S^1$: After all, all proper connected open subsets of $S^1$ are contractible.

@MoisheKohan Yes I am taking $\pi_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb Z$ for granted. I don't see a way to compute $\pi_1(S^1)$ using SvK.

You should tell us what $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are. In particular $\pi_1(U \cap V) = \langle \alpha \gamma \beta \gamma^{-1}\rangle$ is mysterious to me; I would have simply written $\pi_1(U \cap V) = \langle \gamma\rangle$ and then argued that the induced map sends $\gamma$ to $\alpha\beta$.

@MoisheKohan You can use the SvK with the fundamental groupoid instead. It is the same theorem without a basepoint.

@BenSteffan I guess I am implicitly assuming a cellular structure with some orientation when I write that $\alpha, \beta$ are top and bottom edges and $\gamma$ is the identified side edge of the square. I agree that it's mysterious; this is basically what I'm confused about. I'd like to know how to argue what you write: that if $\pi_1(U\cap V)=\langle \gamma \rangle$ then the induced map sends $\gamma\mapsto \alpha \beta$.

@NicolasBourbaki: Yes, of course, and this is one of the reasons Ronnie Brown advocates fundamental groupoids.

@pyridoxal_trigeminus Oh I'm sorry, I somehow completely missed that you defined these things up in the first paragraph. Please forget I said anything :)

Here's something that bugs me about your post. You seem willing, in one step described in your post, so say that $U \cap V$ deformation retracts to $S^1$, and to draw the conclusion that $\pi_1(U \cap V)$ is an infinite cyclic group generated by a certain element. If so, then why are you not willing to say that $S^1 \times [0,1]$ deformation retracts to $S^1$, and that its fundamental group is therefore an infinite cyclic group generated by a certain element?

@LeeMosher As I wrote in the post, the intention was to practice determining induced maps on $\pi_1$ since they often seem to confuse me.

@pyridoxal_trigeminus The induced maps are coming from the inclusion $X\to Y$ if $X$ is a subspace of $Y$. If $\alpha$ is a homotopy class in $X$ then $\alpha$ is the same loop but viewed as a homotopy class in $Y$. For example, $S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$, if $\alpha$ is the circle, then $\alpha$ maps to $\alpha$, however, in $\mathbb{C}$, you interpret $\alpha \in \pi_1(\mathbb{C})$ as the homotopy class in a larger space, and in that larger space it becomes trivial.

Your proof is correct, but it makes things far more complicated than necessary.
You correctly state that $U$ deformation retracts onto $S^1∨S^1$. Then you invoke that $\pi_1(U) \approx \pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$ due to homotopy invariance of $\pi_1$. Actually homotopy invariance is the essential ingredient here.
But if you accept homotopy invariance, then you can more easily use the fact that $X$ deformation retracts onto $S^1$. This shows $\pi_1(X) \approx \pi_1(S^1) \approx \mathbb Z$.
Your argument makes things really complicated.

You need to know that $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \approx \mathbb Z * \mathbb Z$ which can be proved by van Kampen. But it is non-trivial in contrast to $\pi_1(S^1) \approx \mathbb Z$.

You have to compute $\pi_1(X)$ by a pushout-construction as a quotient group of $\pi_1(U) * \pi_1(V) \approx \pi_1(U) \approx \mathbb Z * \mathbb Z $.



The idea was to practice computing induced maps on $\pi_1$, but I agree with what you say. I could also argue that $\pi_1(S^1 \times [0,1])\cong \pi_1(S^1)\times 1 \cong \mathbb Z$ if I assume $\pi_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb Z$. Maybe there are better ways to practice computing induced maps on $\pi_1$. (I'm open to any suggestions).

Let $U$ be the punctured "square" at $(0.5,0.5)$ and $V$ be a small disc around $(0.5,0.5)$.
Then $U$ homotopes to a graph of a wedge of circles. Call one of those circles $\alpha$ and another $\beta$. This means $\pi_1(U) = \left< \alpha,\beta\right>$.
As you said $V$ is trivial.
Now $U\cap V$ homotopes to a circle, and if $\gamma$ is its boundary curve then $\gamma$ is homotopically equivalent to $\alpha\beta^{-1}$.
You need to be careful, you wrote $\alpha\gamma \beta^{-1}\gamma^{-1}$, but there is not supposed to be a ''$\gamma$'', because that corresponds to just the edge along the cylinder, it is a line i.e. homotopes to a point.
So, to avoid the confusion, in my notation $\gamma$ is the boundary curve of that circle, and in your notation $\gamma$ is the edge along the cylinder, but you are not supposed to include that edge as it is trivial!
Thus, $\pi_1(U\cap V) = \left<\gamma\right>$ and $\pi_1(U\cap V)\to \pi_1(U)$ is the map $\gamma\to \alpha\beta^{-1}$.
From here we get the pushout as $\left< \alpha,\beta ~ | ~ \alpha\beta^{-1} = 1 \right> = \left< \alpha,\beta ~ | ~ \alpha = \beta \right> = \left< \alpha \right> = \mathbb{Z}$.

I don't get the point of this answer. You repeat OPs proof almost exactly, give no additional details or justifications about the parts of the proof they are unsure about, and the only thing you actively criticize is misguided: $\alpha\gamma\beta^{-1}\gamma^{-1}$ makes perfect sense if you interpret multiplicative notation to mean concatenation of paths; at worst, OP's notation here is somewhat imprecise.

@BenSteffan How about you let the OP comment on whether the answer is useful or not?

Giving other users feedback on their questions and answers is part of how this site works, and questions and answers are not just for the benefit of the asker and answerer. You're free not to respond to my criticism, of course, but know that I am writing it as much for you as for anybody else to read and evaluate against your answer.

I agree with @BenSteffan comments

@pyridoxal_trigeminus What part of that answer do you need further clarification on? I can on editing that answer until it becomes satisfactory for you.
